# Open link with form action

Tags: javascript, html

By clicking this form action link there is a question mark within the URL like this: example.com/?#about/hello-world .

```
myhoverHTML += "<form action='http://example.com/#about/hello-world' target='blank' onsubmit='touched(this)'></form>";
```

Where does it come from and how can I open the link without it?
Thanks
Hank

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? How do you even submit that form if it's empty?

Comment: What's in the `touched` function? Is that doing anything to the form before submit?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the whole bizarre 'form action link' idea, you *might* be able to get rid of the `?` simply by adding `method="post"` as another `<form>` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of odd having the hash tag (`#`) where you do in the URL.  Is it really necessary to have it?  Did you mean to use `http://example.com/about/hello-world` as your `GET` address instead?

Comment: I dropped the "<form action" and this is my new code: `mycont += "<div class='mydivclass'>";
mycont += "<a onclick=openwebsite(this)' title='mytitle' class='myclass' /> </a></div>";

function openwebsite(imgpath){
window.open("http://www.example.com/#bookmark/"+imgpath) 
 }` Everything is working except the -imgpath- is undefined. Does somebody see what I did wrong?  I